# How do I get my social icons to not turn blue? (from hyperlinking)

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, social-networking

Having some issues, tried a few different ways of fixing this but can't get it. First picture is what it looks like in editing, second is what it looks like on the actual site. I want it to look like it does in editing. Here's the code:

```html
<!-- wp:social-links {"size":"has-large-icon-size","align":"center"} -->
<ul class="wp-block-social-links aligncenter has-large-icon-size"><!-- wp:social-link {"url":"https://www.facebook.com/Givemetherecipedammit","service":"facebook"} /-->

<!-- wp:social-link {"url":"https://www.instagram.com/givemetherecipedammit/","service":"instagram"} /-->

<!-- wp:social-link {"url":"www.pinterest.com/givemetherecipedammit","service":"pinterest"} /-->

<!-- wp:social-link {"url":"https://amzn.to/2LXwTzb","service":"amazon"} /--></ul>
<!-- /wp:social-links -->
```

Any help is appreciated! I use Wordpress, this is an automatic block they produce. They weren't any help :(

[image]

Comment: Can you add css to this block? If you can, try `color: white;text-decoration: none;`

Comment: I'm not sure where to add it to? Apparently the code did not paste into my post for some reason

Comment: <!-- wp:social-links {"size":"has-large-icon-size","align":"center"} -->
<ul class="wp-block-social-links aligncenter has-large-icon-size"><!-- wp:social-link {"url":"https://www.facebook.com/Givemetherecipedammit","service":"facebook"} /-->

<!-- wp:social-link {"url":"https://www.instagram.com/givemetherecipedammit/","service":"instagram"} /-->

<!-- wp:social-link {"url":"www.pinterest.com/givemetherecipedammit","service":"pinterest"} /-->

<!-- wp:social-link {"url":"https://amzn.to/2LXwTzb","service":"amazon"} /--></ul>
<!-- /wp:social-links -->

Comment: You should be able to edit your original question to include that code. You need to put ``` (3 backticks) before and after it

Answer (score 0):

A quick fix for this would to add `style="color: white;text-decoration: none;"` to the ul element (e.g. between 'ul' and 'class')

A better idea would to include the following in the css field of your editor if the block allows it.

```
.wp-block-social-links{
  color: white;
  text-decoration: none;
}
```